# Dynamically create component and navigate to it

Tags: angular

I know there is a better way, but i need to dynamically create a component in angular, execute some methods and depending on the results navigate to it. The best way to do this, is to execute the logic in the previous component and depending on the result navigate to it, but we can´t do this.

We are migrating (automatically) a JAVA SWING application to an angular/spring app. We encountered a lot of problems, but we found a solution for all of them, all except this. The conversor is line by line and we cant take code from one window to another.

We know how to create the component dynamically and execute methods on it, and even include it in the activate component, but we are having problems to navigate to it.

We tried to implement reuse-strategy and append the component to it, so we create the component but we don´t know how to route to it.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using `this.router.resetConfig` after you define your new route?

Comment: we don´t define the new route. It is already set. The problem is that we need to instantiate the component (and make some thing on it) before navigating to it